# Pushed ViewController is "greyed out" cannot intact with it

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

Im relatively new to iOS programming and have been making a recipe based app for the iPad. I've looked around at a lot of answers and can't seem to solve my problem so ill explain how my app is laid out.

Navigation controller -> ViewController -Modal segue -> PreviewViewController -modal segue -> Navigation Controller -> RecipeViewController

Within my RecipeViewController i have a button that when pressed i want it to go back to the "home" screen which for these purposes is the "ViewController".

**Here is the code for the button action in "RecipeViewController":**

```
- (IBAction)homeB:(id)sender {
ViewController* viewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

However, when i press this button the ViewController is displayed, but the screen is greyed out and i can have no interaction with the screen. I can't post an image of what the screen looks like as i don't have enough reputation yet but i will update it when i can.

I have tried other ways of displaying it such as connecting a segue in the storyboard between the button and the "ViewController" and then activating the segue when the button is pressed. But this messes up other parts of my code as i have to re allocate and initialise the home screen. Would appreciate any help as to why it is coming up with the greyed out screen that cannot be interacted with.

Also just some more notes:

```
self.navigationController
```

does not return nil so it is seen, and no errors are displayed when the button is pressed.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code for the ViewController class? Is that created programatically, or using Interface Builder?

Comment: Did you make this in a storyboard? Is this your structure: ViewController is the root view controller of a navigation controller. It does a modal segue to PreviewViewController, which then does another modal segue to another navigation controller whose root view controller is RecipeViewController. Is that right? Are you planning on adding more controllers, because this is not a very good structure if you're not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses everyone, i figured out my problem though. My structure was wrong and i realised that i didn't need to have another navigation controller for the Recipe view Controller as i wasn't pushing anywhere from there. So incase anyone else has a similar problem my structure is now as follows:

Navigation Controller -> View Controller -Modal Segue -> PreviewViewController - ModalSegue -> RecipeViewController

I removed the Navigation controller between PreviewViewController and RecipeViewController. This means that they are all modal view controllers. So to get back from the RecipeViewController to the home screen which is "ViewController" i just needed to dismiss the hierarchy of modal views with the following code:

```
UIViewController * parent = self.presentingViewController;
[parent.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I went back two stages so that both the PreviewViewController and the RecipeViewController where dismissed.

Works great now, thanks for the help anyway everyone.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really doing segues, then I presume this was made in a storyboard. If that's the case, then you should use an unwind segue to get back to ViewController. You do this by adding an IBAction in ViewController that looks like this:

```
-(IBAction)comingBackFromRecipe:(UIStoryboardSegue*)sender {
    NSLog(@"I'm back");
}
```

The important point is that the sender type be UIStoryboardSegue. Then in IB, in the RecipeViewController, you control drag from your button to the green "Exit" icon at the bottom of the controller. When you let go, you should see the method that you wrote in ViewController -- connect it to that. This will get you back to the same instance of ViewController that you started with.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing a screenshot, but from what i understand, if you want to go back to the home screen, you shouldn't be pushing a new view controller (unless you really want to add it to the stack?)

To go back to the "home" screen, you should try this:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

or if your home screen is the root, simply use this:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```