# Pushed view controller "Greys out"

Tags: user-interface, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

Here is the Flow

RootVC --PresentsModally--> NavigationController(NAV_A)'s_RootVC --Pushes--> anotherVC --Pushes-->yetAnotherVC..(and so on..)

Upto here every thing works fine

Now there is a segue(lets say "Segue_B") from "anotherVC" that presents modally another navigational stack(lets say NAV_B) and here comes the problem.
All the stack items pushed in the NAV_B are "Greyed Out". 
Every thing works the way I want, its just that they are greyed out.

I read this "[Pushed ViewController is "greyed out" cannot intact with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821919/pushed-viewcontroller-is-greyed-out-cannot-intact-with-it)", but changing the flow is not the option for me.

Also I would like to mention(as I thing the problem lies somewhere here) that NAV_A is the only one that provides the context and defines the context for all child controllers(that includes NAV_B too). And I have defined its sizes as "form sheet" so that all its child are of size "form sheet" and their context is the "NAV_B".

Here is the interesting thing that i noted.

I tried changing the presentation style of the "Segue_B" from "current context" to "form sheet" and then the colors are back.

The question : **Why are colors greyed out in case "current context".**

I am using storyboards,iOS7,iPad application.